# Como saber la cantidad de conexiones realizadas por un usuario en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, php7

tengo un hosting que me brinda bases de datos de MySQL limitadas con  `MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR = 500`, o sea, un mismo usuario no podría conectarse a la base de datos mas de 500 veces por hora, sino la base de datos deja de funcionar.

Quería saber como podría hacer para obtener la cantidad de conexiones que va consumiendo un usuario en MySQL.

Me estoy conectando desde PHP 7.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias

Comment: Hola, @nof , no se si te sirva  ```show processlist``` Un saludo

Comment: gracias @Jozeslond pero no, eso me da los procesos en el momento de la consulta, no la estadistica de conexiones por usuario.

Answer (score 0):

me suena mas a que puedas probar con:

Entrar en la consola del Mysql

`mysql -p`

Listar todas las conexiones activas

`show processlist;`

Listar las propiedades de las connexiones

`show status like '%onn%';`

Comment: Gracias pero no me da lo que busco :(